How to Model Multivariate Time Series Using Nixtla's NeuralForecast in Python Without Including the Target Variable as an Input
I want to a model multivariate time series using nixtla's neuralforecast in python. However, do not want the target variable to be part of the input of model. Lets make an example:
feature1 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100))
feature2 = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100))
target   = feature1  + feature2

I want to model the 'target' using 'feature1'  and 'feature2', without the target being part of the model input.
The model shall learn that 'target = feature1 + feature2', by looking at the past values of 'feature1'  and 'feature2' not at the past values of 'target'.
Here is my current state:
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ds': np.arange(100),
    'y': feature1 + feature2   
    'feature1': feature1 
    'feature2': feature2,  
})

model = NeuralProphet()

# add additional features
model = model.add_future_regressor(name='feature1')
model = model.add_future_regressor(name='feature2')

# assume milliseconds as freq
model.fit(data, freq='L')

My Final goal would be to compare PatchTST and NeuralProphet.

I have exactly the same question, +1
